# Javascript/Typescript Rating Report

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, material-ui

I need to generate a table report and display in table form, count of each rating based on date. Rating is based on 5.
I have the object

```
[
  {
    "Date": "01/11/2022",
    "Ratings": [
      "5", "2","3","1","4","5","2","3","1","4",
    ]
  },
  {
    "Date": "09/12/2022",
    "Ratings": [
      "3","1","4","3","4","3","4","3","1","4","5","2","3"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Date": "08/15/2022",
    "Ratings": [
      "3","1","4","3","4","3","4","2","3","1","4","5","2"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Date": "08/27/2022",
    "Ratings": [
      "5", "2","3","1","4","5","2","3","3","4","3","4","3","1","4",
    ]
  }
]
```

Each row in the table should have cells with
Table head:
Date, 1 rating (count), 2 rating (count), 3 rating (count), 4 rating (count), 5 rating (count)

Comment: That's a list of requirements, not a question. When you tried to implement that what code did you write? What problem did you run into? What error messages did you see? See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on creating a question that is more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to count the ratings per date. As you will need to do that for every day you should use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as your primary operation.

The rest is just a basic HTML table to display the computed results. Here you can use whatever you want, this is just a basic example how you might achieve sometning like that. The React Material UI component library will also have nice components ready for you to use.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "Date": "01/11/2022",
    "Ratings": ["5", "2","3","1","4","5","2","3","1","4",]
  },
  {
    "Date": "09/12/2022",
    "Ratings": ["3","1","4","3","4","3","4","3","1","4","5","2","3"]
  },
  {
    "Date": "08/15/2022",
    "Ratings": ["3","1","4","3","4","3","4","2","3","1","4","5","2"]
  },
  {
    "Date": "08/27/2022",
    "Ratings": ["5", "2", ,"3", , "1","4","5","2","3","1","4", "1"]
  },
{
    "Date": "01/01/2022",
    "Ratings": ["1", , "3", "4" ]
  }
];

function TableRow({ ratingCountPerDay }) {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{ratingCountPerDay.date}</td>
      {ratingCountPerDay.ratingCounts.map((ratingCount) => (
        <td style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>{ratingCount}</td>
      ))}
    </tr>
  );
}

function Table() {
  const ratingCount = data.map(day => {
    const defaultCounts = Object.fromEntries([...new Array(5)].map((_, i) => ([i + 1, 0])));
    const ratingCountObj = day.Ratings.reduce((acc, cur) => (acc[cur]++, acc), defaultCounts);
    return {
      date: day.Date,
      ratingCounts: Object.values(ratingCountObj)
    }
  });

  return (
    <table style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <tr>
        <th style={{ width: "30%" }}>DATE</th>
        <th>1 STAR</th>
        <th>2 STARS</th>
        <th>3 STARS</th>
        <th>4 STARS</th>
        <th>5 STARS</th>
      </tr>
      {ratingCount.map(it => (
        <TableRow key={it.Date}  ratingCountPerDay={it}/>
      ))}
    </table>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<Table/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: TableRow results are not right if one of the rating is missing, say if "Date": "01/11/2022",
    "Ratings": [
      "5", "2","3","1","4","5","2","3","1","4",
    ]

Comment: The example you have given has worked before, however there was an issue when there was no rating e.g. with 4 stars or so. I've adjusted the code to use default values now, so 0 will be displayed in that case.